# ajax request not getting SET-COOKIE from server in phonegap kitkat?

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cookies, cordova

I am making a ajax request to a server and it returns a cookie which contains my user_id. SO i parse it to get userid.

This is working till android 4.3 in phonegap but with 4.4 it fails. After the ajax complete i get all response headers except set-cookie.

i use jquery 1.9x and phonegap 3.3

Here is the request:- 
$.ajax({

```
           url:urlValue,
           data: {email:email,pw:pass,login:1},
           contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
           type : "POST",
           crossDomain: true,
           dataType: 'json',
           cache: false,
           xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },               
           success: function(response,status,xhr) {
                    // do something
                   }
                  error {
                   // check error
                  }
                  complete function (jqXHR, textStatus){
                 console.log(jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders()); 
               // here i do not find cookie by header "set-cookie"
                 }
```

Comment: Got the same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies do not seem to be supported in PhoneGap as I have the same issue.  However, response headers do seem to work.  On the server, instead of setting a cookie, you can set a header on the response object the retrieve this from Javascript.